# JavaScript JSON parse returning undefined

Tags: javascript, json, undefined

I have the following function

```
function getSetting(item) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", "settings.json", true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            var data = JSON.parse(rawFile.responseText);
            return data.item;
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

which I am testing like this

```
console.log(getSetting('restaurant_name'));
```

It is returning **undefined**

a console.log of **data** returns the JSON object of my JSON file, as expected.

a console.log of **item** returns **restaurant_name**, as expected.

I must be missing something obvious, but having looked at the other topics on Stackoverflow related to this I haven't come across anything yet.

I have tried using **data[0].item** to get the result but it also made no difference.

The contents of the settings.json file:

```
{
  "restaurant_name": "Example_Restaurant_Name",
  "restaurant_address": "Example Restaurant, England"
}
```

Help much appreciated in advance, thanks.

Comment: You just dont understand, that async functions dont have to return anything, instead you have to lear how to deal with promises and callbacks

Comment: @webdeb - Thanks. I did have a callback as per wmorrell's example before - it is data[item] _vs_ data.item that threw me off as every example I saw of getting JSON values referred to data.item for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are using an incorrect form of object lookup, as-is your code is looking for an `item` name on the JSON.
2. There is no way for your function to directly return from an asynchronous request.

Try this instead:

```
function getSetting(item, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", "settings.json", true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            var data = JSON.parse(rawFile.responseText);
            callback(data[item]);  // <----- THIS LINE CHANGES
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

getSetting('restaurant_name', function (value) { console.log(value); });
```

Comment: Yes, I would  provide a second argument, like `getSetting(item, callback)` and explain how to use it..

Comment: Doh, completely skipped over that, I'll edit to include.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the return statement.

```
return data.item
```

This is going to try to return a value in the data object for the key 'item', when what you want is to return the value in the data object with the key stored in the item variable.

I think the correct syntax for what you want is:

```
return data[item]
```

I also don't think that you can return a value from your function here - so you'll need to either define a callback function once the async request has returned the value, or set a variable that's scoped outside of the function.

Someone else just posted an answer that makes use of a callback function, so I would suggest using that approach.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that makes sense.